# Checking the derivative of function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Lef $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R $ be defined by

$$f(x,y)=\sin\left(\frac{y^2}{x}\right)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

if $x\neq0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $x=0$. Then show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

It is clear that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Now by the definition of derivatives of function of several variables, the derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is going to be a linear map say $\lambda$ which satisfies the condition

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{ |f((0,0)+(h_{1},h_{2}))-f(0,0)-\lambda(h_{1},h_{2})|}{\Vert h \Vert} = 0$$

So how can we show that f is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Should we assume that f is differentiable at (0,0) and then try to get some contradiction in the condition of differentiability? Or there is some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f$ were differentiable at $(0,0)$, then this limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left\lvert\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{(x,y)-(0,0)}\right\rvert=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left\lvert\sin\left(\dfrac{y^2}{x}\right)\right\rvert$$
would exist. But it is not the case, since, taking $y=a\sqrt x,x\to0$ we get the limit to be $\sin a^2$ which is different for different values of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$f_{x}(0,0)=f_{y}(0,0)= 0$.
But  expression

$$\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_{x}(0,0) x- f_{y}(0,0) y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{y^2}{x}\right)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  =  \sin\left(\frac{y^2}{x}\right)$$

have not $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} =0$, which can be shown if, for example, we consider  $y=\sqrt{x}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f$ were differentiable at $(0,0)$ then you know that $\lambda$ (the total derivative at origin) has to be equal to $(f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0))$. So just check whether $\lambda = (f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0))$ satisfies the definition of total derivative as you mentioned, if this $\lambda$ doesn’t satisfy the condition of the definition then $f $is not differentiable at origin for any other choice of $\lambda$.